# Htaccess Rewrite meeting a character limit before rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have this Rewrite Rule but I want to modify it so that only 7 character strings will meet that criteria. I can't figure out how to do this and i'm not even sure if its possible.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/?$ rewrite.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `{7}` instead of the `+`:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]{7})/?$ rewrite.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

This will match only 7 letters and numbers,

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]{7,})/?$ rewrite.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

This will match 7 or more letters and numbers.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]{1,7})/?$ rewrite.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

This will match more than one or more and seven or less letters and numbers.